# P5 creates <main></main>, how do I prevent that?

Tags: javascript, html, p5.js

Every time my p5 script is executed, it puts an empty main tag into the body.

Maybe it is because of my setup(but I don´t think so):

```
function setup() {
  let canv = createCanvas(400, 400), // TODO https://p5js.org/reference/#p5.Element/parent
      mainFrame = createElement('main'),
      mainDiv = createDiv();
  mainDiv.parent(mainFrame);
  canv.parent(mainDiv);
  .
  .
  .
}
```

Here is how the result looks like:

```
<body>
  <main></main>
  <main>
    <div>
      <canvas id="defaultCanvas0" class="p5Canvas" width="400" height="400" style="width: 400px; height: 400px;"></canvas>
    </div>
  </main>
  .
  .
  .
</body>
```

Is there something like `preventDefault()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep a reference to the previous container before you set it to another and delete the previous one later.

```
function setup() {
  let mainFrame = createElement('main'),
  let canv = createCanvas(400, 400);
  // keep a reference
  let originParent = canv.parent();  
  canv.parent(mainFrame);
  // delete it now
  originParent.remove();
}
```

If you are running in `instance mode`, you can pass a `node` to the p5() constructor like this. This will prevent the `main` been created in the first place.

```
const s = p => {
  p.setup = function() {
    p.createCanvas(400, 400);
  };

  p.draw = function() {
  };
};

new p5(s, document.body);
```

Future reading about how it has been created in `global mode`.

The `global mode` creates the element by `new p5()`, [source](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/blob/main/src/core/init.js#L35), without passing a `node` as a parameter like we did in the example above in `instance mode`, so here, [source](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/blob/c1640a7cb11c25145e9b9dd561ba27f7b49fcde4/src/core/rendering.js#L89) you will see how the `main` node has been created,

```
  if (this._userNode) {
    // user input node case
    this._userNode.appendChild(c);
  } else {
    //create main element
    if (document.getElementsByTagName('main').length === 0) {
      let m = document.createElement('main');
      document.body.appendChild(m);
    }
    //append canvas to main
    document.getElementsByTagName('main')[0].appendChild(c);
  }
```

The `_userNode` was assigned to the parameter we passed in, which is `global mode` it's not there, so it created a `main` element as the container.

Answer (score 0):

This line: `mainFrame = createElement('main')` creates a tag `main` and adds it the DOM. That's what you see being added to the DOM.

You can simply replace all the code you posted with simply:

```
function setup(){
    let canvas = createCanvas(400,400);
}
```

That's all! The rest of the code only does exactly what you don't want it to do. If you ever want to put the canvas inside another element, simply pass in the parent element's `id` as the parameter to `canvas.parent()`

For example:
HTML:

```
<div id = "canvas-container"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function setup(){
    let canvas = createCanvas(400,400);
    canvas.parent("canvas-container");
}
```

Comment: "_This line: mainFrame = createElement('main') creates a tag main and adds it the DOM. That's what you see being added to the DOM._" this is the <main> I want to have not one I don´t want. I am intentionally creating it.

Comment: Oh I see. That makes a lot more sense. Thank you for clarifying. Is it entirely necessary that you remove this empty main tag, or can it just stay there? It may be a lot of hassle to remove it, although I'm sure it's possible if you really want to.

Comment: That´s what I´m now questioning myself. I only want to have the following order: **<main>** > **<div id="TicTacToe">** > **<canvas>**. But I can´t use plain JavaScript since I already started with P5. *sigh

Comment: I've worked with p5 a lot in the past (and present) and I can confirm that if you want to make a tic-tac-toe game that you can _absolutely_ do that with p5. Simply create your canvas, center it on the page (or don't), and draw to it. It's incredibly simple. If you would really like me to I could even whip you up a small demo tomorrow when I have time. But don't get discouraged! I promise you that it's possible and it doesn't require anything special. :)

Comment: thank you for the offer but I already got the tic-tac-toe inside the canvas and a small winning sequence(*very proud). but I was told seperate it from the rest of the html so someone else could reuse my tic-tac-toe in another/bigger project

Comment: Ah I see! Sounds good man. :) I'm proud of you too! Good work. And good luck with your future projects.